# Ubuntu Install fails after GRUB from USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, kernel

[System Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl1Vw.jpg)

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu on the above system. Every time, the installer fails to launch with either a loop or a Kernel Panic. I've tried both ubuntu server and lubuntu several times and remade the install USB at least once for each. I upgraded the BIOS to 7A33v45 with no change. I've tried the USB in both front and back panel USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports. I've verified that the USB is UEFI and FAT32. The Kernel Panic looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWTfu.jpg) and the loop looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiOxD.jpg). Windows 10 Home is currently working on this system. Any thoughts on ways to get the installer to actually launch such as boot options?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? I read 17.10 had problems and people had to use 17.10.1 instead.

Comment: I tried server 17.10.1 and lubuntu 17.10

Comment: You may need several UEFI settings. MSI X370 Gaming Plus used rEFInd
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2378837 Also what video card or does your system have internal AMD video? nVidia needs nomodeset boot option and many AMD need IOMMU settings and Some Gigabyte boards need acpi=off boot parameter also.

Comment: The GPU is an AMD RX 570

Comment: 1. Please tell us which tool you are using to create the USB boot/install drive,https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick  ; 2. Check that the iso files match their `md5sum`, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes; 3. Please try with some boot options, for example nomodeset, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. When on grub screen, go to "Install Ubuntu" and press "e". This will open an edit window. Either 3rd or 4th line down (can't remember), delete the words "quiet splash". Then press F10 to boot. This works for me every time I install Ubuntu on a new hard drive/system.

Also, I disable secure boot in the bios.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried so many things. Finally found that you should have a separated partition to load windows and select that partition to install grub on it.

Windows calls this partition as `System Reserved` and it's `500 MB` for Windows 10.

I should mention that I got this problem since I installed an Extra SSD on my computer.

Comment: I don't think I've gotten this far. The installer itself doesn't make it past GRUB.

Comment: You should make that partition before getting the installer started.